# When to what when building a linear model?

Tags: model, linear

There a many tools to building linear models, such as adding non-linearity, adding splines, adding interactions, variable selection.

It can feel overwhelming when considering all of the options…
For example, should you try interactions first or try polynomials?

Coefficients and P-values slide around with changes, so it is apparent that depending on your early decisions in building a model…you can end in very different places with your model (including different variable selection).

So, what should be done when?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I fear this question might be too broad to work on here, and I think that because Frank Harrell's answer to this question fills an [entire book](https://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/0387952322).

Comment: Frank Harrell also has freely available [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your scenario and/or the question you try to answer.

When data provides reason to use non-linearity instead of linearity, you should consider doing that. It could also be that e.g. [physical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) knowledge or behavior require to use a nonlinear model. Note, in statistics linear and non-linearity differs from average understanding.
If you want to figure out which parameters dominate/influence your object/subject, you have to check e.g. p-values and effect sizes or run tests (t-test, Anova and so on). When you want to consider interactions (like how is temperature combined with humidity affecting your medium), you have to consider this in a model.
When you want to compare students across universities you have to consider a mixed model and so on.
It all depends.